# how can i test my Grain which depends on another Grain?

Tags: unit-testing, orleans

```csharp
class GrainB : Grain, IGrainB
{
    public async override Task OnActivateAsync()
    {
        var grain = GrainFactory.GetGrain<IGrainA>(0);
        await grain.Register(this.GetPrimaryKeyString());
        await base.OnActivateAsync();
    }

}

class GrainA : Grain, IGrainA
{
    public Task Register(string grainKey);
    public Task UnRegister(string grainKey);
}
```

there is two Grain named GrainA and GrainB. GrainB depends on GrainA. I saw the Orleans's sample and the `TestGrainFactory` can create a local grain which I can test.
when Grain is simple, it can be tested easily. but in my problem, GrainB depends on GrainA, how can I complete the test?

Comment: what unit testing framework are you using?   Are you using TestCluster from the nuget package Microsoft.Orleans.TestingHost?

Comment: If you want to purely unit test the Grain you can mock out the GrainFactory by using this constructor: https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/blob/master/src/Orleans/Core/Grain.cs#L55
You can then mock out the GrainFactory returned by the GrainRuntime.